# Referring to uniforms without glGetUniformLocation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3, opengl-4

in my shaders I like to use a syntax like this:

`layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;`

So that I can just use the index `0` in `glVertexAttribPointer` and the such, saving the effort for the `glGetAttribLocation` call. I'd like to do the same with `uniform` values, but if I do

```
layout (location = 2) uniform float offset;
```

My vertex shader fails to compile. Is there any way to achieve the same behavior and not use `glGetUniformLocation`?

Comment: Have you considered using UBOs instead of plain uniforms?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with them yet, what benefits would they have here?

Comment: you could use `std140` layout where you would not to have to query a thing. You also might be able to more efficiently group your uniforms by update frequency, and you can also use the same UBO for different shaders without having to keep update the uniforms separately for each shader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenGL 4.3 or the ARB_explicit_uniform_location extension](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location) allows you to specify uniform locations within the shader using that syntax. So your shader `#version` needs to be 430 or you need to activate the extension in your shader to be able to use this syntax.

Comment: Oh I see! If I wanted to target older hardware instead, is it mandatory to use `glGetUniformLocation` for uniforms? And generally how old or bad do GPUs (even integrated ones) to not support 4.3?

Comment: @memememe: This is not really a hardware feature; it's purely an API change. So the availability of the extension depends entirely on how recent the driver is. Do you want to support hardware that itself hasn't [seen a driver update since 2013](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location&option=not)?